# Does Xamarin.Social uses Facebook SDK to initiate Login?

Tags: facebook, xamarin.ios, xamarin

In the October 2, 2013 breaking changes Facebook specifies that:

> "Native apps on iOS and Android must use our iOS and Android SDKs to initiate Facebook Login."

So I was wandering if `Xamarin.Social` is going to continue working after this changes take place and if not what could an alternative be?

Comment: Shoud you not be asking this to Xamarin? Anyways, I am pretty sure if the changes will affect the component they will soon roll out an update.

Comment: I think this is a topic of general interest, the answer to which should be relevant not just for me but to other developers using this technology. Stackoverflow is better for that than direct contact to Xamarin support.

Comment: I never meant Xamarin support, I meant Xamarin Forums, which would be a good place to ask so all Xamarin Devs can get the info. SO is fine too but Xam Forums sometimes yeild's quicker responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xamarin.Social does not use the native Facebook SDK to login. However, we believe Xamarin.Social to be exempt from this change due to the fact that it uses the website based login.

You can test things yourself going into your Facebook app settings, under the advanced section, and enabling "October 2013 Breaking Changes".

Comment: On the Settings > Advanced section of Facebook Developers Page for this app there is the option to select [web] as Authentication type. With this selected, and the "October 2013 Breaking Changes" enabled, as you suggested, everything seems to work. Thanks